# Supernatural: Why do Sam & Dean pursue Abaddon, etc?

Tags: supernatural

Okay, so here's the thing: Sam and Dean know the entire process to close the gates of Hell and banish all demons forever from the Material Plane/Earth/this Universe. In fact, they even start season 9 with a captive demon and the problems they faced in the previous season have been forgotten as Abaddon rose to power. In all that, why doesn't Dean, who was deadset on it for the whole previous season, complete the trials himself, rather than search for a way to kill Abaddon? After that, with Abaddon gone and Dean a demon, why didn't Sam then go to the storage area where he knows one of Crowley's hellhounds is stationed (Season 9, Episode 21), kill it, and then get one of the reapers working for Cass to sneak him into Hell to save a soul, and then cure Dean, following up with the rite? After that point, I can understand why they might have forgotten about it, but they both had perfect opportunities and motives to complete the trials in Season 9 for Dean and Season 10 for Sam. Why do they seem to care so much more about killing a single demon than killing them all? In both those cases, they didn't have the other brother to stop them from sacrificing themselves.

Comment: IIRC, they figured out in  Season 8 that closing the gates of hell would _kill_ whoever did the trials; the one constant behind the whole show is that neither of them wants to let the other one die, no matter how badly the world is screwed up as a result.

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but the point is in early Season 9, Dean could have sacrificed himself without any harm to Sam, and in early Season 10, Sam could have sacrificed himself without any harm to Dean. In fact, in the latter case, it would've helped to ensure that Dean was cured. In either case, the other brother wasn't there to stop the self-sacrifice, so you've missed the point. I hope I have clarified

Comment: And what after that? When they realized that the other has sacrificed themself, you think it wouldn't hurt the one left?

Comment: I love the series and have watched most of the episodes many times. And, the inconsistencies in the canon plus the plot holes drove me crazy until I just accepted the fact that the showrunners did not do the best job of maintaining continuity, finishing plot arcs, etc. I am happy "fixing" them in discussions with other fans and writers of fan fiction. Trying to make sense of the mistakes made by producers and writers can make one dizzy. Okay, I sort of forgive them - 15 years and all - but nonetheless, it is, in my opinion, a lost cause. Not an answer, just sympathy.